# Store Procedure compiling but value are not getting updated or inserted

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-luw

I have created below stored procedure in Db2 Server Platform - LUW and version is v10.1.0.6. The stored procedure is getting created absolutely fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TAS_TEST
(
    IN I_LOGIN_ID VARCHAR(20),
    IN I_NAME      VARCHAR(100),
    IN I_C_NAME    VARCHAR(100),
    IN I_USER      VARCHAR(20),
    IN I_DEBUG     SMALLINT DEFAULT 0
)
MODIFIES SQL DATA
LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN

DECLARE V_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE V_TOKEN VARCHAR(36);

SET I_LOGIN_ID = TRIM(I_LOGIN_ID);

IF I_LOGIN_ID IS NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '20000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'LOGIN ID IS MUST:';
END IF;
IF I_NAME IS NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '20000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'NAME IS MUST:';
END IF;
IF I_C_NAME IS NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '20000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'C_NAME IS MUST:';
END IF;
IF I_USER IS NULL THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '20000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'USER IS MUST:';
END IF;


MERGE INTO TOKEN_DETAILS AS TD
USING(
    SELECT
        I_LOGIN_ID,
        I_TOKEN,
        I_NAME,
        I_C_NAME,
        I_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE,
    FROM TOKEN_DETAILS
) AS TEMP
ON(TD.I_LOGIN_ID = TEMP.I_LOGIN_ID)
WHEN MATCHED AND TEMP.I_TOKEN IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE
    SET
        I_TOKEN = V_TOKEN,
        I_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE = V_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    
    INSERT INTO TOKEN_DETAILS(
        I_LOGIN_ID,
        I_TOKEN,
        I_NAME,
        I_C_NAME,
        I_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE,
        I_CREATED_DATE,
        I_CREATED_BY
    )VALUES(
        I_LOGIN_ID,
        V_TOKEN,
        I_NAME,
        I_C_NAME,
        V_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        I_USER
    );

    SELECT I_TOKEN "TOKEN" INTO V_TOKEN FROM TOKEN_DETAILS;
    SELECT I_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE "TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE" INTO V_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE FROM TOKEN_DETAILS;
END;

GRANT EXECUTE TAS_TEST TO ADMIN;
```

However, while calling/executing the stored procedure, it's not either updating or inserting the value in the table

> CALL TAS_TEST('testuser','service','component','testuser',0);

Can someone please let me know where I might be wrong.

Comment: The last two lines don't make sense. You could get any result out of that, not necessarily the most recently merged row

Comment: Multiple errors. You don't set either V_TOKEN or V_TOKEN_EXPIRY date before using them for update/insert. You don't increment the timestamp on the update. You are missing a where clause on the source-table for the merge (presumably the where clause should be based on the input parmeters),  and other mistakes...

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems...
You use parameters with the same names as table column names. If you don't qualify them, then you must know the rules used by Db2 to determine, if it's a column or variable or parameter.
[References to SQL parameters, SQL variables, and global variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0056419.html):

> Names that are the same should be explicitly qualified. Qualifying a
> name clearly indicates whether the name refers to a column, SQL
> variable, SQL parameter, row variable field, or global variable. **If
> the name is not qualified, or qualified but still ambiguous, the
> following rules describe whether the name refers to a column, an SQL
> variable, an SQL parameter, or a global variable**:
>
> - **If the tables and views specified in an SQL routine body exist at the time the routine is created, the name is first checked as a column name**. If not found as a column, it is then checked as an SQL variable in the compound statement, then checked as an SQL parameter, and then, finally, checked as a global variable.

Back to your example, especially the following code:

```
MERGE INTO TOKEN_DETAILS AS TD
USING(
    SELECT
        I_LOGIN_ID,
        I_TOKEN,
        I_NAME,
        I_C_NAME,
        I_TOKEN_EXPIRY_DATE,
    FROM TOKEN_DETAILS
) AS TEMP
ON (TD.I_LOGIN_ID = TEMP.I_LOGIN_ID)
WHEN MATCHED AND TEMP.I_TOKEN IS NOT NULL THEN
UPDATE ...
```

You merge into the same table and compare every row by the same `I_LOGIN_ID` table column. Every row of `TOKEN_DETAILS` has match `ON (TD.I_LOGIN_ID = TEMP.I_LOGIN_ID)` (unless the table is empty). The `UPDATE` works only for rows where `I_TOKEN` column `IS NOT NULL` setting the value to `NULL` since `V_TOKEN` variable is not initialized before `MERGE`.

Your `SELECT INTO` statements at the end will fail, if `TOKEN_DETAILS` contains more than 1 row.